# Existing application changing from database c# asp.net mvc core

Tags: c#

So I developed an application which uses a database to get it's information. This database exists out of one table with 32 columns. So I have one model "Home" which has 32 Properties. My application has a DbContext which looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Home> homes { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new HomeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

And HomeConfiguration looks like this:

```
class HomeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Home>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Home> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable<Home>("Home");
        // Mappen Primary key
        builder.HasKey(t => new { t.Month, t.Number });
    }
}
```

The connection is made in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddSession();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>();
}
```

The repository constructor looks like this:

```
public HomeRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
    _homes2 = dbContext.homes;
    _homes = new List<Home>() { new Home() };
}
```

And based on that repository all methods are configured.
Now I find out that in production this database I have based this application on is nothing alike. They are actually 2 seperate databases who each have multiple tables (like it's usually the case, I won't say I found it weird when I started with this database but it was not my place to question the task I was given).
So now I'm wondering, is there a way to make this transition without practicly starting completely over? Can I somehow map these databases in a way so that my Home object can still contain all the 32 Properties or is this a no go?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What DBMS are the databases on?

Comment: @squillman judging by code example it's sql server

Comment: @Konrad ... of course.  Time for more coffee.

Comment: It is indeed sql server